# Is it possible to put pictures into an album as they're being taken?

Tags: images

My wife uses her S10+ (probably upgriading to an S20 or S21 soon) to take document properties for our work. When it comes time to do the quote, she has to scroll through a billion photos to get to the one she's after. She's really busy during the day and it's annoying to put them into albums after the fact. Is there a way she can make a new album and as pictures are being taken to automatically deposit them into the "current" album?

Comment: I assume she's using GeoTagging when taking the photos at the properties? In that case, an alternative approach would be using a gallery app that can sort by location, like [these apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_galleries#group_201) offer. That could also be done at the desktop (there is software for that on Linux, Mac & Windows certainly). A third option would be marking time (property-start and property-end); file names usually carry time stamps, so grouping shouldn't be too hard that way either.

Comment: Use a file explorer that can sort the view to show latest, for instance [solid explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2) //create from the explorer a shortcut on to your home screen

Comment: @beeshyams I'm not sure you're following the use case. She needs to access it weeks later.